# Java nested Map/List - filter by list contents, returning parent object

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-stream

I have two string arguments to my function - "Pizza", and "Chips". I'd like to use streams to return the author whose "foods" key has contents matching these two strings

```
List<String> collection = Arrays.asList("Pizza", "Chips");


private static List<Map<String, Object>> authors = Arrays.asList(
    ImmutableMap.of("id", "author-1",
                            "firstName", "Adam",
                            "lastName", "Awldridge",
                            "foods", Arrays.asList("Pizza", "Chips")),
    ImmutableMap.of("id", "author-2",
                        "firstName", "Bert",
                        "lastName", "Bruce",
                        "foods", Arrays.asList("Pizza", "Fish")),
        ... // other authors
        );
```

This is my attempt with streams:

```
return authors
                    .stream()
                    .filter(authors.stream()
                            .flatMap(author -> author.get("foods"))
                            .findAny(queryFoods))
                    .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

I want to return the first author who's foods match that of my query. I think the main difficulty is organizing data - unfortunately I can't get the following casting to work.

```
.flatMap(author -> (List<String>) author.get("foods"))
```

Also, this might stream through the authors too many times (I should use .filter on the stream I just made with

```
authors.stream()
```

Comment: Do you want authors that match all foods in your query or is a single match enough?

Comment: I'm looking for all matches only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you cannot directly treat the value of foods key as a List. Its just an Object. So, first you need to do an instance of check and if it is an instance of List, then you can check whether it contains the values that are there in your collection.

```
Map<String,Object> firstAuthor =  authors
                                        .stream()
                                        .filter(author -> {
                                            Object foods = author.get("foods");
                                            if(foods instanceof List) {
                                                List foodsList = (List) foods;
                                                return foodsList.containsAll(collection);
                                            }
                                            return false;
                                        })
                                       .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

OUTPUT: 
{id=author-1, firstName=Adam, lastName=Awldridge, foods=[Pizza, Chips]}

The above code will give you the required author if it exists or else null. 
[Here, I have assumed that you want to check whether the author has all the food items that are present in collection object created by you. If you want to check for only one of the items then you can use **contains()** method from java.util.List instead of **containsAll()** method. Also, you will have to iterate over the collection object to check for each item in collection.]

Comment: That's perfect. My workaround was to create an "Author" class with a "containsAllFoods" static method (returns boolean) - which I can use in my filter. However, that makes things a little weird as I have to do author.getMap.get("foods").

Comment: It works that way as well, or what you can do is have a method outside itself which takes list of foods for author and the collection of foods which you want to check against. That you it won't coupled with your Author class.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it by filtering in stream:

```
Map<String,Object> author =  authors.stream()
                                    .filter(a -> a.containsKey("foods"))
                                    .filter(a -> a.get("foods") instanceof List)
                                    .filter(a -> ((List) a.get("foods")).containsAll(collection))
                                    .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: I can guarantee that my "foods" values will be a list (even if it has 0 entries) - so I just got my casting wrong (I should have used (List), not (List<String>).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
         authors
                    .stream()
                    .filter(a -> a.get("foods").stream().anyMatch(x -> "Pizza".equals(x)))
                    .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: I want all the foods ("Pizza" and "Chips" to be in a.get("foods") - I'm going to write my solution as an answer.